# Possible GPU memory leak of cv::ogl::Texture2D when copying from cv::gpu::GpuMat?

Tags: opengl, opencv, memory-leaks

I noticed obvious GPU/cuda memory usage increase when I called cv::ogl::Texture2D's copyFrom method. Is this a bug of opencv or am I doing something wrong?

The code snippet is shown below:

```
cv::ogl::Texture2D ofTexU; 
cv::ogl::Texture2D ofTexV;
ofTexU.create( cv::Size( imgW, imgH), cv::ogl::Texture2D::Format::RGB );
ofTexV.create( cv::Size( imgW, imgH), cv::ogl::Texture2D::Format::RGB );

cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuMatU;
cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuMatV;
gpuMatU.create( cv::Size( imgW, imgH), CV_32FC3 );
gpuMatV.create( cv::Size( imgW, imgH), CV_32FC3 );

...// some processing code

while( 1 ) {
    // The following two lines introduced GPU memory increase, and it's keep increasing
    // If commented out, everything looks fine
    ofTexU.copyFrom( gpuMatU );
    ofTexV.copyFrom( gpuMatV );
}
```

BTW, I used cudaMemGetInfo to get the GPU memory usage, as shown below. And I'm using OpenCV 2.4.6, compiled with OpenGL and Cuda support.

```
size_t free_byte, total_byte ;
cudaError cuda_status = cudaMemGetInfo( &free_byte, &total_byte ) ;
if ( cudaSuccess != cuda_status ){
    printf("Error: cudaMemGetInfo fails, %s \n", cudaGetErrorString(cuda_status) );
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug. Thanks for your report. I submitted a patch that should fix the issue: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/1825